# ViewPager2 recreating fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

I have three fragments

```
MainFragment // Fragment with ViewPager2 

ItemFragment // Fragment of the item of the adapter ViewPager2 that contains the RecyclerView 

PreviewFragment // Fragment to which I navigate after clicking on any RecyclerView item in the ItemFragment
```

When I go `MainFragment -> PreviewFragment` (exactly like that, not from ItemFragment) then on return back the `ItemFragment` is re-created from scratch. It is understandable because in `OnCreateView` I do this:

```
viewPager.adapter = MyAdapter(this)
// Add items
```

Tried saving `MyAdapter` like this:

```
private val adapter: MyAdapter by lazy { 
    MyAdapter(this)
}
```

But it leads to a [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606656/viewpager2-crash), all the solutions described there did not help me.

I also tried to save fragments anywhere, in any repository and cache them there and then add them, but this leads to a bunch of leaks in the LeakCanary of ViewPager2.

In general, I would like to hear how this problem is solved, namely, you need to somehow save the state of the ViewPager2 items, perhaps they really need to be cached somewhere

P.S  The main reason why the re-creation of fragments bothers me is that the scroll position of the RecyclerView gets lost